# Compiling pcapy on pyCharm

Tags: python, pcapy

I am trying to use `import pcapy` on one of my python files on PyCharm.

So, I have successfully installed `pcapy` on "Project Interpreter" but when I run the python file including `import pcapy` it says,

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How could I fix this?

Also, I have anaconda prompt, and installed `pcapy` successfully, by using

```
pip install pcapy
```

And the result was:

```
Successfully built pcapy
Installing collected packages: pcapy
Successfully installed pcapy-0.11.4
```

So, it is installed correctly, but why can it be not compiled?

Comment: Did you install `Libpcap` ?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not *activate* your Anaconda environment before trying to use it in PyCharm. Trying to use unactivated environments in Pycharm is unsupported by Anaconda, and can lead to problems like this. So you have two options to fix this issue:

Either use anaconda prompt, activate your environment from there and launch PyCharm from there, or re-install anaconda/mini-conda with the option "add-to-path" checked. This will ensure that PyCharm can activate your environments automatically.